# Register a new file type in Android

Tags: android, file-type

I want to write a simple STL (geometrical data file) viewer application on Android, but I'm not able to make recognize a format to the system. I wrote this in my app manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sla" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But the moment I launch the browser and go to download some sample STL file, the download is interrupted and I'm reported that the data file type is unknown for the system.

I have no real Android device, so I use only an emulator, and for development I use C# on MonoDroid (but I honestly don't think that is the problem).

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: I am just guessing, but you could try to leave out the host element. Also logcat may show you what intent with what pattern is 'coming in' so that you get a better understanding what the system is looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm using this manifest to register (for example) a .stl file type with my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.test.core" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Testy" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="ThorActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="LokiActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="OdinActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl" />
                <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl" />
                <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.stl" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

As you can see, I'm linking the .stl file extension to the activity `OdinActivity`. Inside the `OdinActivity`, I use the following line to get the file path so I can open it:

```
filePath = getIntent().getData().getEncodedPath();
```

Then I just open it to read from it:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
```

Comment: hm.. I tried, to change the .mmmm format to well known one (I used PDF). Go to my GMail account and tried to download a DPF from one of the mails I have. I got exactly same negative result. So i have some doubts: do I need implement my custom ContentProvider to declare esplicitly where I would like to put data that Android is going to download ? It sounds really strange to me, that support of the custom format is so tricky... :(

Comment: Hm... You tried .pdf? Since that is a very common file type, probably it is already registered to another application. I don't know if you can overwrite that setting with your program. Have you tried with the file type you want, STL?
If you just want the association on your smartphone, and don't care about it not beng by code, you could always do this:
Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications and choose the one that is the default now and click the Clear Defaults button

Comment: Yeah, I tried with STL too. So the reason to try PDF, as it well known format and supported almost by everyone, to understand what is wrong . But strange thing is that even with PDF I got the same negative result, as I wrote. I use an emulator not real device, so I wonder if something wrong to use an emulator for this case.

Comment: Check my first answer, I edited to include more details of how I do it. I hope it helps.

Comment: What Permission do i need to Include. what is the mime type

Answer (score 8):

I am surprised that [gnclmorais' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-a-new-file-type-in-android/4838863#4838863) should work. Because it, having multiple `data` entries in one `intent-filter`, did not work for me. What did work in the end was multiple `intent-filter` in one `activity`:

```
<activity
  android:description='@string/Activity_Description'
  android:icon='@drawable/ic_launcher'
  android:label='@string/Activity_Name'
  android:name='net.sourceforge.uiq3.fx603p.Calculator_Activity'
>
  <intent-filter>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'
    ></action>
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'
    ></category>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_pf'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Program'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:pathPattern='.*\\.pf'
      android:scheme='file'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_df'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Datafile'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:pathPattern='.*\\.df'
      android:scheme='file'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_af'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Allfile (Data and Program)'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:pathPattern='.*\\.af'
      android:scheme='file'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_pf'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Program'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:mimeType='application/x-fx-602p.program'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_df'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Datafile'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:mimeType='application/x-fx-602p.data'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter
    android:icon='@drawable/ic_fx_603p_af'
    android:label='FX-603P Simulator Allfile (Data and Program)'
    android:priority='1'
  >
    <category
      android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'
    ></category>
    <action
      android:name='android.intent.action.VIEW'
    ></action>
    <data
      android:host='*'
      android:mimeType='application/x-fx-602p.all'
    ></data>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note that having both `pathPattern` and `mimeType` in one `data` entry did not work either. Last, but not least, I would suggest a few null checks when getting the file name:

```
   /**
    * <p>Open calculator and load file (if one was passed).</p>
    * @see android.app.Activity#onStart()
    */
   @Override
   public void onStart ()
   {
      android.util.Log.d (Calculator_Activity.TAG, "+ onStart");
      super.onStart ();

      final android.content.Intent intent = getIntent ();

      if (intent != null)
      {
         android.util.Log.d (Calculator_Activity.TAG, "> Got intent : " + intent);

         final android.net.Uri data = intent.getData ();

         if (data != null)
         {
            android.util.Log.d (Calculator_Activity.TAG, "> Got data   : " + data);

            final String filePath = data.getEncodedPath ();

            android.util.Log.d (Calculator_Activity.TAG, "> Open file  : " + filePath);

            // File loading comes here.
         } // if
      } // if
      android.util.Log.d (Calculator_Activity.TAG, "- onStart");
      return;
   } // onStart
```

The actual loading of the file is missing from the sample. It should be inserted after the “Open file” log command.

Comment: Im surprised that you surprised :). You see gnclmorais solution used for only one and only file extension (stl) and your solution is about different file extensions (pf, df, af and so on). Obviuosly you had to use several intent filters each one for every extension

Comment: @Stan And why should multiple `android:scheme` work any better then multiple `android:pathPattern`? I can't see any obvious reasons for that. Obscure reasons — yes there are always those. But not obvious. Note that if you look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html you will see that all examples only have one `<data>` section per intent.

Comment: What kind of mime type is "application/x-fx-602p.all" ? How is that constructed? Did you register it in some way for the system to recognize it?

Comment: it is a "x-" type. A user defined type. Everybody can define "x-" type whenever he or she likes.

Answer (score 7):

I tried the other solutions and this is the only one which works for me:

```
<intent-filter
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Armro File"
    android:priority="1" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="ftp" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myowntype" />
</intent-filter>
```

Why do the other ones not work?

Comment: i dont know Why do the other ones not work,but know only this worked for me Also! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to recognise the format as follows:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.yourextension" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several pitfalls with `intent-filters` I ran into, but I finally found an example that worked here: [Android intent filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300649/android-intent-filter-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) in Tim Autin's answer

- The path pattern matcher of Android is implemented in a non-greedy way which is why several answers propose to add several path patterns (see [pathPattern to match file extension does not work if a period exists elsewhere in the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400072/pathpattern-to-match-file-extension-does-not-work-if-a-period-exists-elsewhere-i))
  For me the patterns starting with a slash worked best (i.e.)
   `<data android:pathPatern="/.*..*..*..*..*\\.myextension" />`
- A combination of mime type filters and file name filters happens to filter too much so I ended up with an intent filter for file extensions and another one for mime types
- For the file extensions I somehow required two intent filters: one for the wildcard mimetype `<data android:mimeType="*/*" />` and one intent filter without mime type in the tag at all.

So like proposed in Tim Autin's answer using these three intent filters worked in the end