# Android: Downloading and Handling Unknown File Type

Tags: java, android, file, types, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android app that communicates with a microcontroller via Bluetooth.  I am able to pair and connect with it but I want to send a file that I've downloaded through the Android browser through Bluetooth.

Although, the file type that I hosted online and downloaded is a custom file type that Android does not recognize.

I've read and tried the solutions in this thread: [Register new file type in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android)

but had no luck.  I tried adding the intent-filter but I had a feeling it had to do with the Android file system and not my app itself.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?  What would be the best way attack this?

**tl;dr: How do I get Android phones to recognize my custom file type so that it can be used?  (My phone does not allow it to be downloaded since it does not recognize the file type).**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get Android to recognize your file, you could try changing the file extension to a known type ( ie. foo.yft to foo.jpg or perhaps even no extension? ) and then either letting your micro use it with the fake extension, or adding a bit of logic to rename it after the transfer.