# register new icon for new file type in android

Tags: android, icons, file-type

I can register an extension to open with my app as described in [Register new file type in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android) but how we can use a new icon for new file extension?

Comment: You probably can't. I would assume that the file explorer determines the image used for any given file type, and if the file explorer doesn't actually recognize said extension, then it would use it's default image for unrecognized extensions. It could potentially be possible - I just don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea. but i dont think we can do that. File explorer gives the icon automatically.