# Intent filter for common file explorers

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm trying to associate my app with extension. I have read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518318/android-how-to-create-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension-that-does-not-make) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension) about the problem. But major file explorers (like es file explorer, astro, file manager by Rhythm software) can't open my files.

My `manifest` file:

```
<activity android:name="com.comapping.android.map.MapActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.comap" android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.comap" android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

And If I try to open file from my application using next code everything works fine (chooser not shown):

```
String extension = "";
int dotIndex = downloadedFile.lastIndexOf('.');
if (dotIndex != -1) {
    extension = downloadedFile.substring(dotIndex + 1, downloadedFile.length());
}

// create an intent
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadedFile));
String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
if (type == null || type.length() == 0) {
    // if there is no acceptable mime type
    type = "application/octet-stream";
}
intent.setDataAndType(data, type);

// get the list of the activities which can open the file
List resolvers = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
if (resolvers.isEmpty()) {
    (new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setMessage(R.string.AttachmentUnknownFileType)
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.NeutralButtonText, null)
            .create()).show();
} else {
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

If i try to open it using OpenIntents file manager everything is normal - showed long chooser with lots of apps and my app in the list.

But if I try to open it with es file explorer or Rhythm file explorer - showed their custom chooser (open as text/image/video/audio). It's bad.

And if I try to open it with Astro - it opens OpenIntent's file manager. It's also bad.

Is there any solution of the problem? Who is wrong in such behavior?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem here is all the different ways people wrap a shared intent for, say, a file that resolves to text/plain in Android mime identifier.

My approach has been to find out what mime types the files I want are. Then I set my manifest filters to those types. I use two filters. The first just filters the mimes I want. The second is a copy of the first plus schemes.

Then I test by sending shares from apps like you have done. When one does not work, I use a toast to see what I am getting for a STREAM and then alter it to fit. For example, if I get an OpenIntent STREAM, I have to remove

```
content://org.openintents.filemanager
```

which leaves me with the path. Mostly, I just have to remove:

```
file://
```

But it's always something because the whole content/Uri/Intent scheme is a free-for-all cluster whatsit.

LATER. I just stumbled on this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();                
String name = intent.getData().getPath();
```

Maybe that will do for you. I'm going to try it soon myself.