# android intent filter for custom file extension

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to make an android app to open files with extension .abc and this is my application section from android manifest xml

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="com.example.app.ActName" android:label="AppName">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I used all the experience from the most popular and related questions

[Android intent filter for a particular file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

[Android intent filter: associate app with file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension)

[Android How to create Intent Filter for custom file extension that does NOT make it part of a chooser for everything on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518318/android-how-to-create-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension-that-does-not-make)

And in the end this does not work - when I click on a file named "name.abc" in ES file browser it asks me if i want to open the file as text or image etc. when it actually supposed to just open the file in my app instead

### What am i doing wrong? What is the proper intent filter to launch the app by just clicking a file with the corresponding extension in any file manager?

## upd.

it looks like different android systems and different file browsers act in different way - one intent filter works just fine on 4.2 in "ES File Explorer" and on 4.0.4 in default file manager, but does not work at all on 4.2 and 4.0.4 in "Total Commander" and on 4.0.4 in "ES File Explorer"

Comment: with the same code I can have options on long press on "name.abc" file is text,audio,video,image.

Comment: @PratikSharma , and this is not the way it should work, I think . I changed the question to describe that.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the first `intent-filter` in your example uses MIME type `image/jpeg`. Is `jpeg` your `.abc` extension?

I think there may be three reasons why this does not work:

1. You need to add more MIME types. Try adding the following:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:mimeType="application/abc"/>
   </intent-filter>

   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
   </intent-filter>
   ```

   And, if your `.abc` format is a text format:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
       <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. You have registered the `file` scheme. You might also need the `content` scheme:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="content" />
       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
       <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.abc" />
       <data android:host="*" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
3. [Rumor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153391/1839209) has it that `pathPattern` with a dot only matches files containing a single dot. In your example, this would mean that your app would be associated with `One.abc` but not with `Two.Dots.abc`. Try adding more pathPatterns `.*\\..*\\.abc`, `.*\\..*\\..*\\.abc` etc.:

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="file" />
       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
       <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.abc" />
       <data android:host="*" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with "files" app of Google: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files&hl=en and of Google Drive. Any idea how to support there too?

Answer (score 1):

if you try it in samsung my files it doesnt work so you have to do this

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

Because app is not done correctly, its samsung poorly coded my files app

Comment: Works perfect on the samsung my files application, everything else fail and there is no clue how samsung developers try to open the Intent. Checked on Android 12, Samsung A21s. The problem is that it may open every single file of the system so it is still not usable :(

Comment: Samsung Files pass an empty string as the mime type when they don't recognize it, which is impossible to catch in any other intent filter.