# Associate file extension with Xamarin Android application

Tags: android, file, xamarin, intentfilter

I am trying to associate a custom file extension with my Xamarin-based Android application.  I would like my application to open when the user chooses a particular type of file from the file manager.

My files use the extension ".label" but for some reason I cannot get Android to add my app to the chooser listen when selecting a file with such file extension.

However, if I use the ".xml" extension it seems to work.  Here is the `IntentFilter` I am using:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.ActionEdit },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "file",
DataHost = "*",
DataMimeType = "*/*",
DataPathPattern = ".*\\.xml")]
```

Comment: you need to speify mime type of your extension .Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256537/android-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension

Comment: actually, removing DataMimeType completely worked out for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.ActionEdit },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = "file", 
    DataHost = "*",     
    DataPathPattern = ".*\\\\.label")]
```