# Share / Copy To from "e-mail" to Xamarin App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to "Copy To" / "Share" attachment to/with Xamarin App from e-mail. Basically make my application to show up in list of applications where file can be copied to or shared with? Could you please provide an examples(or share links) how it can be done, both for iOS and Android? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can check `Xam.Plugins.Messaging` first.

Answer (score 0):

File associations (Open In) are done differently on [iOS](https://dzone.com/articles/ios-file-association-preview) & [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521996/associate-file-extension-with-xamarin-android-application) as you can see in the links I attached.
You can also take advantage of the Xamarin Essentials [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher) for this, but for iOS you have to make info.plist changes, as shown in part [1](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/associate-a-file-type-with-your-ios-application) & [2](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/ios-tips-and-tricks-associate-a-file-type-with-your-app-part-2)

You are essentially enabling the system to realize that your app handles those links, and then you enable your app to do work when it is opened through those links.