# Manifest registered Activity no longer working with Intent Filter(s)

Tags: android, file, android-intent, manifest

I have read several questions and answers in the forum, without getting a reason for why my manifest registered Activity is not being executed (and previously was)

Not duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256537/android-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518318/android-how-to-create-intent-filter-for-custom-file-extension-that-does-not-make) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760276/android-intent-filter-associate-app-with-file-extension) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

I have ensured that the Manifest is correctly spelled.

I have rebuilt the project

I have invalidated the Android Studio cache

I have altered the scheme with `*`, or `file`, or `content` and others, without any difference in behavior (clicking in a File, in a File Browser showing as no application options, when it used to behave correctly in the same device, and same application)

This was working, and the Activity was being requested (when a File was clicked) however, it has then stopped working, and I am unable to understand why.

Manifest Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.FileLoaderActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.dvc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pfl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.voc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.dvc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.pfl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.voc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.dvc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.pfl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.voc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.dvc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.pfl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.voc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.dvc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.pfl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.voc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are you sure that when file is clicked, you are not getting `content://` scheme?

Comment: this one not your launcher activity...right?

Comment: @egoldx I have also tried other schemes, such as  `*`, `http`, `https`, `content`,  and many others, but it appears to behave the same.

Comment: @AshwiniViolet No. This is a separate Activity, my Launcher Activity is called "Launcher", and is behaving properly with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an update, in the "File Browser" application, that altered `android.intent.action.VIEW` to `com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA`, thus rendering the concept of "View Intent" invalid.

This is for "Samsung" only. In other Devices, the system is behaving as expected