# File opening with a defined new file format

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that use its own file format.

I want that when the user click on a file with extension `.myAppFormat`from any file manager

I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android) to understand how to register a new file format.

My problem:
How to get the full file path on opening to allow my method to load the file?

My method is something like:

```
public void loadFile(String path){
FileInputStream savedSerializable = new FileInputStream(path);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your activity is newly created, in `onCreate()` you can call `getIntent().getData()` to get the `Uri` of the file that triggered your activity.

If your activity instance already existed, call `getData()` on the `Intent` that is delivered to your `onNewIntent()` method.

Comment: How exactly should I manage these 2 different situations? My Activivity could exist or could be closed if the user hasn't started the app

Comment: @AndreaF: I have no way of answering that, as I am not the one writing your app. I would expect that many apps would use `onCreate()` to set up and populate the UI, and use `onNewIntent()` to populate the existing UI.

Comment: Yes I use `onCreate`e also in all my `Activity`... but assuming that I'm in activity `B` where `B` isn't the main Activity... how could listen if someone is trying to open an associated file, so that I can switch  to the home `Activity` in the appropriate way?

Comment: @AndreaF: The activity that has the `<intent-filter>` matching the `Intent` will come to the foreground if it already exists, automatically.

Comment: ok... thank you! I will try your suggestion and eventually accept the answer if works.

Comment: get `java.lang.NullPointerException` if I try `getIntent().getData().getEncodedPath();` I have also tried to do `Intent i=i.getIntent() if(i!=null){string path=getData().getEncodedPath();` but get same issue

Comment: @AndreaF: Open up a fresh Stack Overflow question, showing your code and the complete stack trace.

Comment: I have used a try catch to avoid the issue... if the app is already opened the solution works, otherwise hangs. details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620337/if-i-try-to-register-a-file-associaton-the-app-hangs-at-the-start