# If I try to register a file associaton the app hangs at the start

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried to register a new file association using the suggestions answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android)

I want to open the main `Activity` of the app if the user try to open the registered file type

According the accepted answer in the `Manifest` I have tried this code

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.myfilextension" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.myfilextension" />
                <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.myfilextension" />
                <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                    android:pathPattern=".*\\.myfilextension" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but the `.myfilextension` seems not correctly associated, since if I try to open a file `sample.myfilextension` nothing happens.

So I have tried

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="ftp" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myfilextension" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With this code, if I try to open a file `.myfilextension` and the App has been launched and is running in background everything works fine, but if the app is closed when I try to open the file, the app try to start but hangs, in the emulator hangs on "*wait for debugger*" soI cannot understand the cause of the issue.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sample code should work.

> in the emulator hangs on "wait for debugger"

The problem seems related to the Emulator that cannot attach the debugger.

Try to follow these steps:

-Close the Emulator

-Go to AVD manager and recreate the emulator again

-Start the emulator and try to run the app

Alternatively try to run the app on a real device.