# Associate app with file extension in titanium and phonegap

Tags: cordova, titanium, phonegap-plugins, titanium-mobile, file-association

I am trying to know if it is possible to assign app to open a file association by default.

I have created a new file format that I use to store encrypted data, and I want to my to be started and passed the file when the file is double clicked.

Is there a way to associate a phonegap application with a given file extension?

An example where this has been done using java is:
[Register new file type in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799576/register-new-file-type-in-android/8638084#8638084)

**Please note that**

*1- I know that I can write my own plugin.*

*2- I have searched the phonegap plugin directory with no luck so far.*

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress, i am looking for a plugin for the same functionality as well

Comment: Sadly not but appearently it is possible in cordova using plugins.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34610913/5718968) SO Answer may help you as well.