# Open custom file extension with Flutter App

Tags: flutter

How can I assign (or associate) a custom file extension `(.foo)` to an FlutterApp `(BarBaz)`, and then any time that the user select a file from the file manager, the dialog show this app to open the file.
Later my app can manage this file inside of it, and hanlde its contents.

Like a audio player associate audio files to it, and open it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried many variations [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062112/10148111), but none of them worked.
After few days, I found and tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55976817/10148111) that helped me.

So, I solved it by adding this code to my  ***/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml***:

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
    ...
        <activity>
        ...

            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

                <data android:host="*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.YOUR_CUSTOM_EXTENSION" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
            </intent-filter>

        ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```