# Android Intent filter pathPattern doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have following link that I want to trigger my `Activity`:

`http://mypage.com/custom-description-text-with-some-random-numbers-a21-id20683066.html`

And intent filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="mypage.com"
                android:pathPattern=".*-id.*.html"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately this `Intent` doesn't work. Does anyone has idea why?

Comment: Could you paste the part of your code responsible for preparing intent?

Comment: I'm just clicking on the link in the gmail. It shows only browser.

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8599921/265597) describes you problem. The easiest solution would be  removing `pathPattern` and checking if Uri has correct pattern in your Activity, but that depends on your app requirements.