# Android's intent-filter matches files regardless of their extension

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want my application to able to open `.src` files with XML content. It partially works; there's one problem I can't solve: it looks like Android doesn't take `android:pathPattern` into account when matching the intent. My `intent-filter` looks like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="text/xml" android:pathPattern=".*\\.src" />
    <!-- path pattern does not match dots correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3400072/44089 -->
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.src" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.src" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.src" />
</intent-filter>
```

Before I added `android:mimeType="text/xml"`, literally every 'view' action was matched to my app, i.e. my app was visible in the application chooser, even if I wanted to see a contact. Fortunately, adding `mimeType` filtering helped a bit. But still, `pathPattern` doesn't seem to change anything in the way my intent filtering works.

I've seen tens of tutorials about this and the code is identical. It must be some weird, unusual case. What am I doing wrong? I'd be grateful for any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `android:path*` attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path):

> These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.

You do not appear to have a scheme.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I added `<data android:scheme="file" />` to my `intent-filter` and now it works as expected. I should read the documentation more carefully... :)