# Android intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml not matching incoming Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

As far as I know, the patterns SHOULD match:

- action = VIEW
- mimetype = any
- host = any
- pattern = Anything ending with .php
- scheme = file

AndroidManifest.xml sample:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.php" android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

Incoming intent data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason why in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400072/pathpattern-to-match-file-extension-does-not-work-if-a-period-exists-elsewhere-i).

tl;dr: The Android team didn't implement it properly. Any filepaths with . in it will not match correctly so we're forced to use hacks.