# Open a certain file type in my app

Tags: android, xamarin, intentfilter

My app generates .smbf files and I want to make an option to open these files in my app when user want to open them using file manager apps.
After searching I found a way using intent filter and this is my code:

```
[Android.App.Activity(Label = "Setting", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden, Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
[Android.App.IntentFilter(actions: new string[] { Intent.ActionView, Intent.ActionEdit }, Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataPathPattern = @".*\\.smbf", DataHost = "*", DataScheme = "file")]
public class Setting : MyActivity
{..}
```

And the generated manifest:

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Setting" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustUnspecified" android:name="md5307edafcc42f816474105a485627044f.Setting">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.smbf" android:scheme="file" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But my app isn't shown in the list of apps that can open *.smbf file. (tested with solid and es file explorers)
Is there anything more that I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved after I added mimeType attribute:
`DataMimeType = "*/*"`
`android:mimeType="*/*`

Answer (score 0):

Are your files located in a path that contains periods?  There's a long-standing problem with using pathPattern like this when there are periods somewhere in the full path.  See my ancient question from 2010.  Nothing has changed with this in 6 years, which is kind of sad.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400072/pathpattern-to-match-file-extension-does-not-work-if-a-period-exists-elsewhere-i](http://Are%20your%20files%20in%20a%20path%20that%20contains%20periods?%20%20There's%20a%20long-standing%20problem%20with%20using%20pathPattern%20like%20this%20when%20there%20are%20periods%20in%20the%20directory%20names%20elsewhere%20in%20the%20full%20path.%20%20See%20my%20ancient%20question%20from%202010.%20%20Nothing%20has%20changed%20with%20this%20in%206%20years,%20which%20is%20kind%20of%20sad.%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400072/pathpattern-to-match-file-extension-does-not-work-if-a-period-exists-elsewhere-i)