# Open activity when link is opened

Tags: android

I want to open my activity when the user click on a link on my web page, pointing to an itr file, currently I've got:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ui.Activity"
    android:label="@string/activity_load"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" android:pathPattern="*.itr"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The web page is opened on http://www.mywebsite.com/contents from this page the user can click on links to itr files. However my activity is not opened, any tips?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8599921/6950238) answer.

Comment: check this out http://christopher5106.github.io/mobile/2015/03/26/web-redirection-to-mobile-web-or-app-with-a-modal-box.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove pathPattern from `data` node in your intent-filter.
Path patterns restricts the uri to follow applied criteria [check here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path)